# SonarScanner CLI error: check sonar.projectKey and sonar.organization properties, SONAR_TOKEN variable

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarcloud, sonarscanner

When using [SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarscanner-for-net/), following the suggested manual recipe for classic .NET and MSBuild - so all required properties and variable are passed to the CLI tool - I find the following error at the bottom lines:

```
ERROR: Project not found. Please check the 'sonar.projectKey' and 'sonar.organization' properties, the 'SONAR_TOKEN' environment variable, or contact the project administrator.
```

What's wrong? How to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the mentioned properties? Have you tried the `SONAR_TOKEN` with something else, e. g. a plain `HTTP GET` against one of Sonar's resources?